# Books on query optimization?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Are there any books on query optimization, preferably for MySQL? I have High Performance MySQL but it doesn't seem to do a great job of giving you the knowledge necessary to optimize any query you might come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "High Performance MySQL" by Baron Schwartz et al, ISBN 978-0-596-10171-8.  A lot of it is on server-side configuration settings and such, but Chapter 4 covers query diagnosis and optimization.

Comment: I somehow forgot about this entire chapter and then somehow didn't find it when I went looking. I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html